# GoogleDoc: ImportHTML

Tags: html, google-docs

I run a fantasy football spreadsheet in aid of Cancer Research UK which incorporates the daily price changes etc. Last season I downloaded the data using the following formula:

```
{IMPORTHTML("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/","Table",1)
```

However, they've made this URL a little fancier in terms of appearance, and from what I've read, they've basically adapted the page from HTML to Javascript.

Does anyone know a workaround formula or perhaps a way I could get this data from the above URL to a GoogleDoc by any other means?

Thanks in advance,
Ryan

Tried editing the formula to look at table and lists within the =IMPORTHTML

```
{IMPORTHTML("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/","Table",1)
```

Hoping to pull through all players and their respective prices (which it did based on the old page). Instead it's now just pulling through an n/a error.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this only using google sheets.

They migrated to an API system, so now their data is in JSON format. For example, this would work in your google sheet:

```
=IMPORTJSON("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/")
```

Here you see we're importing the data as JSON. However, JSON allows for data structures more complex than 2D tables, and the data for the players is in URLs like this:

https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/players?pageSize=30&compSeasons=274&altIds=true&page=0&type=player&id=-1&compSeasonId=274

As you might have seen, the content is blocked. They made it so that only their own webservers can make use of this code, so google sheets will get blocked.

Sorry, seems like they don't like people not visiting their site.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me Dany.